# The page isn't redirecting properly : Error Message while Login into site

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, session-cookies, coldfusion-9

I am facing some weird Issue in my Public website Login Page from past few days.

My website contains Login Page, when I hit on Login button  :
**FF says (The page isn't redirecting properly)
Chrome says (Page has Indirect Loop)**

Temp Solution: Clearing cookie and cache.

Here are my application level settings for  ColdFusion session Management:

```
  this.loginStorage = "cookie";
  this.sessionManagement = true;
  this.sessionTimeout = createTimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0);
  this.setClientCookies = true;
  this.ClientStorage = true;
  this.setDomainCookies = false;
```

[image]Thanks
Sham

Comment: Some code and examples of what you have tried to fix it would be needed for anyone to even begin to try and help you.

Comment: What Scott says. The problem is with your login and/or authentication code, so you need to examine those areas, and if you can't figure it out post the relevant code and details of what you've tried.

Comment: Issue is not recurring, It happens some time only.
FYI: when I check cookie during error then I see CFID/CFTOKEN generated twice
say for Example
XYZ.dev.co : CFID:1231, CFTOKEN:123213
dev.co     : CFID:1311, CFTOKEN:178913

Do this may cause any Issue (Domain Level cookies).

Comment: If you have a redirect loop, use the network tab in your browser's dev tools or use Fiddler to watch the sequence of requests. Normaly your server will be redirecting back the the same URL that issued the redirect. After a few redirects, the browser decides this is a problem with the site and presents the error. Without a bunch of code we probably can't spot the cause, but you ought to be able to capture the sequence of events as it happens with your browser/fiddler. I've had this error in production code and a little `<cflog>` goes a long way to helping work out what's happening